# Definite integral of unknown function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

if
$$
\int_{2}^{5} f(x) dx = 5
$$

what is the value of:
$$
\int_{2}^{5} x^2f(x)dx
$$

Normally I would use integration by parts and try to reduce the $x^2$, but I can't figure out how to do that now.

Comment: Are you able to compute the variance of a random variable by knowing only that it is a random variable?

Comment: In my opinion it is not possible to evaluate the second integral. $f$ could be $f(x)=\frac{5}{s}\delta(x-s)$ with $s$ between two and five.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like it is not possible then. I was challenged to integrate this, so I assumed it could be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $$f_s(x)=\frac{5}{s}\delta(x-s)$$

with $s\in[2,5]$. Then $$\int_{2}^{5} f_s(x) dx = 5$$
but

$$\int_{2}^{5} x^2f_s(x)dx=5\cdot s^2$$