# Find the definite integral of an unknown function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need help to find the definite integral of an unknown function. The hint given was is to use the substitution method, **$u = g(x)$**. There is a similar [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063553/definite-integral-of-unknown-function) posted, but I don't understand the answer proposed.
 If,
$$\int_0^9f(x)dx=4$$
Find,
$$\int_0^3xf(x^2)dx$$

Solution:

$$let \,\, x^2 = u$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}=2x$$

$$\int_0^3xf(x^2)dx=\frac12\int_0^3f(u)du=\frac12[F(x^2)]_0^3$$
$$=\frac12[F(3^2)-F(0)]=2$$

Comment: Replace $$x^2=y$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Why not expand this into an answer?

Comment: @Allawonder, I hope that is too small for an answer but is sufficient hint

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I edited my post with my workings, could you help to see if its correct?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Hence, I talked about *expansion.* In any case I've done this myself.

Comment: The second integral in the last equation is incorrect; the limits of integration are wrong. If $u=x^2$, then when $x$ varies from $0$ to $3$, we will have $u$ varying from $0$ to $9$, not from $0$ to $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y=x^2.$ Then the limits go from $[0,3]$ to $[0,9].$ Also, we have that $\mathrm dy=2x\mathrm dx.$ Thus, the integral becomes $$\int_0^9xf(y)\frac{\mathrm dy}{2x}=\frac12\int_0^9f(y){\mathrm dy}=\frac12×4=2.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have the substitution method in your notes/have seen it somewhere online. I would first suggest writing one of the integrals with a different variable of integration (i.e. replace the $x$'s in one integral with some other letter whenever it shows up). This doesn't change the integral, or really do much to the problem at all, but it might help you better see how to apply the substitution method.

The problem you linked to actually turns out to be trickier than this one--in this problem the $x$ and the $x^2$ are in the proper places for using the substitution method. In that problem, on the other hand, the basic substitution method is not applicable.